# How do I validate a Modelbound item without violating DRY in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelbinders

I'm using the ASP.NET MVC `DefaultModelBinder` to bind a request to a model class, but only using two of its properties:

```
namespace MVCApp.Models
{
    public class Ticker
    {
        public string Symbol {get; set;
        public string Exchange {get; set;}
    }
}

namespace Domain //in another assembly
{
    public class Quote
    {
        public string Symbol {get; set; }
        public string Exchange {get; set; }
        //lots of other properties we need for output
    }
}

public ActionResult ShowQuote(Ticker ticker)
{
    var quote = quoteRespository.GetQuoteBy(ticker);
    return View(quote);
}
```

In the view, they can specify the Ticker and Exchange; and that's ModelBound using the `DefaultModelBinder`.  However, each time we need to actually use this `Ticker` object for something, we need to go to the `QuoteRespository` and get all of the properties populated for that Ticker.

#### Question

Should I get rid of the `Ticker` Object and just create a custom modelbinder to Model-bind to the `Quote` object; and in the Modelbinder make the respository calls to actually fill out the `Quote` object? Or should I violate DRY and make the call to that respository in every place we need a quote?  Is there a built-in framework way of doing this that I'm missing?

It appears there is a school of thought that says [*not* to make service-layer calls in the Modelbinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658425/is-it-okay-to-hit-the-database-from-a-custom-model-binder).

#### Update

I created the Ticker class just because we had these two properties in (almost) every single action:

`public ActionResult ShowQuote(string symbol, string exchange)`

Since they always belong together, I created a small Model class in the UI layer to push them around together (the aforementioned `Ticker` class).  **Ticker is not a view model class, and it isn't meant to be**.

Answer (score 1):

"Or should I violate DRY and make the call to that respository in every place we need a quote? Is there a built-in framework way of doing this that I'm missing?"

You could always retrieve the quote as part of a Quote controllers OnActionExecuting function.

I wouldn't consider this a DRY violation. Just the cost of doing business.  Chances are the way you retrieve quotes won't change and you'll probably have < 10 places were you need this functionality.  Depends on how many times you'll need to include that line.

Better to have short and concise action methods than getting all mangled up in base controller and onactionexecuting stuff.

Don't get into model binding against your repository.  Did it in a previous project and its the worst and most brittle piece of the application.

Comment: We talked about doing the `OnActionExecuting`, but then it's run for every single request, even requests that don't deal with the `Quote` object.

Comment: @George Stocker - I'd put all the actions that need it in the same controller.  You've just told me your controllers violate SRP and have more than one reason to change.  ;)

Comment: They are all in the same controller; but then every action in the controller is making that same exact call.

Comment: @George Stocker - I mean take out all the actions that don't work with the Quote.  Right now you have at least two reasons for that controller to change, when the quote logic changes and when some non-quote logic changes.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to map between view models and domain models.

Comment: It's not really a 'View Model'. It's a collection of properties (like `Symbol` and `Exchange` that really belong together (in a `Ticker`), but there's a lot more a ticker has than just those two properties. So for input it's good to have them together, but I don't want to duplicate the repository call in every action.

Comment: @George Stocker, if Ticker is not a view model class why it appears as argument to a controller action? It's just bad practice to have something else than view models as arguments to controller action the same way that it is bad practice to have a controller action pass something else than a view model to a view. As far as the duplication part of the repository is concerned I am not sure I understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me it would be important to see what does `Quote` contains ? You mention it has other properties for output but does it have other properties and methods which are only relevant to the `Domain` namespace? If yes then I would like to keep an abstraction between the types used for views and the types in your domain namespace.

So you could end up having a `TicketViewModel` which contains everything required by your views and as Darin mentioned, use AutoMapper to map `TicketViewModel` to `Quote`.

**EDIT:**

If you *really* want to ensure DRY, then you can create your own ModelBinder (it's easy, tons of tutorials on Google) and bind your viewmodel from repository in it.

Comment: I'll update my question, since you're the second person to ask that question.

Comment: you could put the repository call in your custom model binder. this will allow abstraction between your view models and domain model + ensure DRY.

Comment: Yea; but there are people out there that say the [Modelbinder shouldn't do that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658425/is-it-okay-to-hit-the-database-from-a-custom-model-binder)?

Comment: I think it's the matter of perspective. For some Model binders are basically encapsulating POST-ed data but for me I use it as an extension to what Controllers already do. If I want to do anything pre-Controller, I put it as a Filter and If I feel like repeating something in Controller, I'll setup a Model binder. The only caveat being that there are cases in your app where you don't want to convert `Ticket` to `Quote`. There you should ensure that it doesn't use your binder and make the db call.